# How do i install tsserver on Lazyvim?

Tags: neovim, liskov-substitution-principle, mason

I uncomment the lazy.lua to install tsserver and jsonls but both are failed to install. Can anybody solve this problem.

[image]

I installed everything that requires to run lazy vim. Then i uncomment the list which i want as LSP. But failed to installed

Comment: azyVim the well-named.

Answer (score 1):

if you in using lua then make a file for lsp-config.lua then add this to the file ::

```
return {
  {
    "williamboman/mason.nvim",
    lazy = false,
    config = function()
      require("mason").setup()
    end,
  },
  {
    "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim",
    lazy = false,
    opts = {
      auto_install = true,
    },
  },
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    lazy = false,
    config = function()
      local capabilities = require("cmp_nvim_lsp").default_capabilities()

      -- Setup language servers.
      local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
      lspconfig.tsserver.setup({capabilities = capabilities})
      lspconfig.eslint.setup({
        on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
          vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePre", {
            buffer = bufnr,
            command = "EslintFixAll",
          })
        end,
        capabilities = capabilities
      })
      require("lspconfig").eslint.setup({})
    end,
  },
};
```

the code for tsserver and eslint and some code complation for tsserver...
if there any problem then i suggest to visit this repos ::

https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim
https://github.com/neovim/nvimlspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#tsserver

Comment: hey can you tell me the path where i would create lsp-config.lua file?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: okay https://github.com/yossefsabry/vim-lazy-configuration/tree/main/lua/plugins visit this link this my nvim configurtion using lazy you can to clone the repo and source the init.lua file then its will work but you must donwload the lsp-config from mason by type :Mason in cammed mode the search for the lsp-confg you when then install then its gone work with you if you dont went to clone the repositery then i suggest to visit lsp-config git repo its explain every thing in details https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig